# How can I detect if the Solution is initializing using the DTE in a VisualStudio extension?

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, envdte, vs-extensibility, test-explorer

I am using the DTE to track when projects are loaded and removed from the solution so that I can update a custom Test Explorer extension. I then trigger a container discovery process. But when the solution is first loaded it does an asynchronous load of some projects and fires a lot of Project Added events.

What I would really like to do is to ignore all of these events until the solution is done loading. I can't quite figure out the order of events such that I know for sure that this initialization process has completed. It would be really nice to be able to just query the solution object and ask it. Does anyone know if there is a property or interface or event that I can use to determine this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to hook the [`OnAfterBackgroundSolutionLoadComplete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionloadevents.onafterbackgroundsolutionloadcomplete.aspx) event, which is raised when the Solution is fully loaded.

I don't know whether there is a DTE equivalent.

Comment: So I would have to have a package and implement this interface somehow? Right now I'm just subscribing to dte events and don't have a package at all.

Comment: You should be able to get any required services from the [global service provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.serviceprovider.globalprovider.aspx), I think.  Unfortunately, I no longer have an environment in which to test this out, otherwise I'd post an example.  :-)